# React no inicia al iniciar docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Cuando inicio docker con el comando `sudo docker-compose up -d` me marca que de ah iniciado tanto flask como react pero cuando ejecuto el comando `sudo docker-compose ps` para ver por que puerto escuchan y flask escucha por el puerto 5000 pero react solo se queda en restarting.

[image: Inicio de docker]

Como pueden ver lo inicia solo por unos instantes pero después solo se cae.

```
version: '3'

services:
  cloud-flask-back:
    container_name: flask
    build: ./Flask
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ./Flask:/cloud
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
    restart: on-failure
  cloud-react-front:
    container_name: react
    build: ./front-cloud
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./front-cloud:/cloud-front-end
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    restart: on-failure
```

Hola que tal, ya arregle el problema al parecer no me habia dado cuenta que al subir el proyecto a gitlab se omitió una carpeta dentro del archivo .gitignore, la elimine de este archivo y lo volví a subir, hice un git pull desde el otro sistema y reconstrui el docker, muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Hola, Master. Bienvenido. ¿Podrías, por favor, copiar el contenido del docker-compose.yml y/o el Dockerfile para poder conocer un poco más el entorno y ver cuál podría ser la causa del problema? Gracias.

Comment: Es importante tambien que compartas tus Dockerfiles ya que en ambos services estas utilizandolos.